# Negative decimal value formatting in Altova Style Vision

Tags: xpath, altova

I have a problem with value formatting in Altova StyleVision. Altova forums seem to be dead. Maybe someone encountered similar problem.

I have created an Auto Calculation inside XBRL table generated by StyleVision. It contains " sum( xbrli:xbrl/n1:Wages ) " xpath expression. This expression gives me a negative value. I want to format it so that it's surrounded by parentheses instead of leading minus.

I have tried using prefixes ans suffixes in "value formatting", like this (###,##0.##) or this [###,##0.##] . But I still get minus instead of parentheses. Is there a way to get around this? Any of those prefixes seem not to work for me at all.
http://manual.altova.com/Stylevision/stylevisionbasic/index.html?svpres_inputformatting.htm

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It seems that problem is solved. 
Created ch.xsl file with following contents:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:decimal-format name='ch' grouping-separator=" "  decimal-separator=","/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In Altova StyleVision under **Design Overview** -> **Add new XSLT file**. Choose ch.xsl. 
Afterwards in Auto Calculation xpath  used following expression:
format-number(sum( xbrli:xbrl/n1:Wages ),'### ##0,##;(### ##0,##)','ch')

Maybe there is a better way to do this, but it worked for me. Hope it will help someone